# MariaDB connector vs MySQLdb connector - transaction issue

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, spring-transactions, connector

We are migrating from the MySQL connector to the MariaDB connector. We are using Spring and the Bitronix transaction manager.

When we changed connector, we are facing several issues with transactions. Probably we have found the root cause: **differences between handling joined transactions with MySQL and Maria**, please see details below:

We are using this annotation on several places in the project:
`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

Here is the differences in implementation:

**MySQL connector, MysqlXAConnection#isSameRM  implementation:**

```
if(xaresinstanceofMysqlXAConnection){
 return this.underlyingConnection.isSameResource(((MysqlXAConnection)xares).underlyingConnection);
}
```

**MariaDB connector, org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaXaResource#isSameRM implementation:**

```
//Typicallyusedbytransactionmanagerto"join"transactions.Wedonotsupportjoins,
//soalwaysreturnfalse;
return false;
```

Is there someone who faced the same issue? How to handle it?

Our implementation:

```
/**
 * Implementation of Audit Log which saves data using JPA in new transaction.
 */
public class JpaAudit implements AuditSPI {

    @Autowired
    private AuditlogRepository auditLogRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void log(AuditLogEntity aAuditObj) {
        auditLogRepository.save(aAuditObj);
    }
}
```

Changing `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` to `Propagation.REQUIRED` helps but I think it is not way for us.

Comment: This is an issue in driver as you indicate. bug report done : https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-825

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your question was reported ([CONJ-825](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-825)) and corrected ([commit 70c406b2](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-j/commit/70c406b2c0ef8349428a08244af63c0357261991)) by Diego Dupin (thanks to him).

The main part of the commit is in [src/main/java/org/mariadb/jdbc/MariaXaResource.java](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mariadb/jdbc/MariaXaResource.java) :

```
 @Override
  public boolean isSameRM(XAResource xaResource) {
-    // Typically used by transaction manager to "join" transactions. We do not support joins,
-    // so always return false;
+    if (xaResource instanceof MariaXaResource) {
+      MariaXaResource other = (MariaXaResource) xaResource;
+      return connection
+          .getProtocol()
+          .getUrlParser()
+          .equals(other.connection.getProtocol().getUrlParser());
+    }
+    return false;
  }
```

This fix is included from [MariaDB Connector/J 2.7.0.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-j-270-release-notes/)

Comment: @Insidel If this answer satisfy you, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark on the left of it.